# how to accept negative values for amount textfield with this regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to accept a negative value to the text field by without disturbing  the functionality for following regular expression :

```
(?!^0*$)(?!^0*[.]0*$)^[0-9]{1,8}([.][0-9]{1,2})?$
```

for ex : -12.12, -1223233.23, -32323.32

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean? You want to modify the regex without *disturbing it*? You will have to modify it a bit, you know.

Comment: Please help me on this.

Comment: I do not understand the second "number" `-1223233-23`. Is it a real test case?

Comment: I am sorry for too many variants I post in comments. I have just taken your regex and amended it a bit to include the minus. [`^-?(?!0*$)(?!0*[.]0*$)[0-9]{1,8}([.][0-9]{1,2})?$`](https://regex101.com/r/xD8bD2/1). Please check and let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot @stribizhev. It's working now as I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex has lookaheads that are each triggering at every location inside a string. To make the regex more efficient and easily adjustable for a fix like the one you need, you need to move the `^` out of the lookaheads: `^(?!0*$)(?!0*[.]0*$)^[0-9]{1,8}([.][0-9]{1,2})?$`.

Now, you need to add an optional minus at the start. "Optional" means *1 or 0 occurrences*. In JavaScript, you can use a **`?`** quantifier for that (in POSIX BRE, you would have no other alternative but `\{0,1\}`).

So, use

```
^-?(?!0*$)(?!0*[.]0*$)[0-9]{1,8}([.][0-9]{1,2})?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xD8bD2/2)

The regex breakdown:

- `^` - start of string
- `-?` - 1 or 0 hyphens
- `(?!0*$)` - make sure there are no zeros up to the end of string (return no match if a zero is found)
- `(?!0*[.]0*$)` - make sure there are no zeros + a dot + zeros up to the end of string
- `[0-9]{1,8}` - match 1 to 8 digits
- `([.][0-9]{1,2})?` - 1 or 0 sequences of...

  - `[.]` - a literal dot
  - `[0-9]{1,2}` - 1 to 2 digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Hi stribizhev, the above regular expression is not accepting the last two digits of decimal part. It is accepting only one digit as [0-9], it is not accepting last digit as [1-9] it simply taking as zero without interaction...

Comment: What is the input string you are using? It does not accept `33.` and `33.333`, but it does accept `33.3` and `33.33`. BTW, you only asked to add the optional minus ***without disturbing the functionality for following regular expression*** - which I did. I did not change anything. So, if you have another question - please ask.

Comment: for ex : positive number takes as 12345678.12 as input, but the negative number is taking  the same number as -12345678.10, it should be -12345678.12 right??

Comment: I do not get your point, all the numbers above [are matched OK](https://regex101.com/r/mP3yL4/1).

Answer (score 1):

Just add `-?` to make the negative sign optional, or simply `-` if it's mandatory.

`(?!^-?0*$)(?!^-?0*[.]0*$)^-?[0-9]{1,8}([.][0-9]{1,2})?$`

Edit: Fixed

Comment: Did you try it yourself? It [does not match `-12.12`](https://regex101.com/r/wV2zH1/1). Check the `^` anchor position and adjust the lookaheads with your optional group.

Answer (score 0):

THis validates an integer (positive or negative)

```
^-{0,1}\d+$
```

This validate a decimal number (positive or negative)

```
^-{0,1}\d*\.{0,1}\d+$
```

Comment: FYI, the `?` operator is (among other things) the equivalent of `{0,1}`.